# How to change schema per request with Django & Oracle?

Tags: python, django, oracle, model

I need to find some way to change schema per request on Django & Oracle.

is there any way ?

thanks

Comment: I mean for all models in one place - one function or somthing. thanks

Comment: When adding additional information or clarification please edit **edit your question**. The comments section is for things which are comments i.e. which can be deleted with affecting the question. I suggest you spend a little more time framing this question. It is really unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Generally: Changing your DB schema is something that should be done rarely and with care. If you find yourself needing to automate constant changes to it, _especially_ in response to user input, it's almost certain that there is a very major issue with your design. While an [entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) approach might be appropriate here, it's impossible to know without further information, and I'd be hesitant to suggest anything other than stepping back and seriously reconsidering what you're trying to do.

Comment: @kungphu thanks for you comment. The reason I want to do that- I have 2 customer - same CMS - just want to change scheme by hostname. is that sound ok? any idea how? thanks again

Comment: Ah, do you mean switching between schemas, rather than actually applying changes to a schema? I'm not sure if you can apply a global change like that per request, but if you could, it'd probably need to happen in [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/). Django's multi-DB support is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/).